# Do I need to set JAVA_HOME on MacOS?

Tags: java, macos, java-home

I'm fairly new to Java. Many of the tutorials on installing Java on a Mac recommend setting up the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. However, Java works fine on my computer with the `JAVA_HOME` variable being empty!

I have successfully used Java from the ***command line*** (using `javac` and `java`), in ***IntelliJ IDEA*** (there in the "Project Structure Settings" I've set up the "JDK home path" to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home)` and in ***Sublime Text*** to compile and run Java files.

So, my questions are:

- Why does Java work without the `JAVA_HOME` on my Mac?
- Do I need to set up `JAVA_HOME` at all? What would be the consequences of not having it? Maybe it is not essential for some things, but is required for other things to work? Then what are these things?
- Is this behavior different on other operating systems?

---

Outputs of some commands are:

`echo $JAVA_HOME` outputs an empty line

`echo $CPPFLAGS` outputs an empty line

`which java`

```
/usr/bin/java
```

`echo $PATH` contains `/usr/bin`

Comment: Note that Java itself doesn't need JAVA_HOME and many applications that depend on Java probably also don't need it. However, if you have multiple Java installations, a non-standard location or one that actually requires JAVA_HOME to be set, then you'd need it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does Java work without the JAVA_HOME on my Mac?

Setting `JAVA_HOME` is not required for Java to work in your system. Some applications (e.g. Tomcat, Maven etc.) however look for `JAVA_HOME` system variable and if its value is not set, they may prompt you to do so.

> Do I need to set up JAVA_HOME at all? What would be the consequences
> of not having it? Maybe it is not essential for some things, but is
> required for other things to work? Then what are these things?

Already answered above.

> Is this behavior different on other operating systems?

It's same across all operating systems.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the program.

Most programs that depend on Java follow logic like this

```
if $JAVA_HOME ; then
  use JAVA_HOME/bin/java
elif $(which java); then
  use java command on PATH
else
  error
fi
```

That being said, to be *consistent*, you should set it , and using [SDKman](http://sdkman.io/) or Homebrew does that for you